# Made users members of the group that owns the directory, but they still cannot access it

Tags: permissions, chown, ownership

I wanted to make a share folder for my parents.

I created a system user with adduser, created a home folder which I wanted to use as a share folder. The name of this folder is share, the name of the user is shareacc and made my parents and me belong to that group. So it happened that the folder in `/home/share` does not belong to shareacc. So I used

```
chown -c shareacc:shareacc /home/share
```

and it looks like the home folder still not belong to this group and/or user. But if I look this up as root with nautilus it says me it does belong to this group. See Image. Left Root, right is normal.

[image: Screenshot including properties]

How can this be fixed or what am I doing wrong?

The output of `ls -la` in /home is

```
/home$ ls -la
insgesamt 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 root            root     4096 Dez  3 12:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root            root     4096 Nov 23 17:20 ..
drwxr-x--- 42 cornelius-admin sudo     4096 Dez  3 12:09 cornelius-admin
drwx------ 29 dorothea        dorothea 4096 Nov 28 18:39 dorothea
drwxrwxr-x  3 root            root     4096 Sep  8 21:12 .ecryptfs
drwxr-xr-x 20 paul            paul     4096 Nov 28 13:34 paul
drwxr-xr-x  2 shareacc        shareacc 4096 Dez  3 12:16 share
```

and the output of the command in the folder itself is

```
/home/share$ ls -la
insgesamt 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 shareacc shareacc 4096 Dez  3 12:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4096 Dez  3 12:16 ..
```

Comment: Can you print the output of `ls -la` on that directory?

Comment: Here you are. I put it in the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want other system users that are part of the `shareacc` group to be able to write to `/home/share` you need to make it writable,

```
chmod -R 775 /home/shareacc
```

**Note:** `-R` makes the `chmod 775` recursive, i.e all files & sub-directories within `/home/shareacc` will be 775 as well.

It can also be achieved with,

```
chmod g+w /home/shareacc
```

That will give user rwx, group rwx, and others r-x.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/chmod-command-examples/

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But how did it knew that I wanted to make it rw for this group?

Comment: How what knew that? You instructed the computer, with the help of `chmod`, to assign those permissions :)

Comment: @Booming The owner of the directory was the intended user. The group was the intended group. All `chmod` did was say "the user assigned to this directory can do these things and members of the group assigned to this directory can do those things and everyone else can do the other things.". It didn't need to know the group and user because they were already assigned to the directory; if you changed the owner and group it would change which owner and group got those permissions.

Comment: Why did you use the `-R` flag here? That is generally bad advice, and should come with a warning, since the `-R` flag to `chmod` is the cause of so much woe...

Comment: @Zanna As OP wants to share that entire directory, my thought was that there might already be directories within it that needs to be chmodded as well. But I get your point, I'll put a note about it in the answer.

Comment: you could also add that we rarely want to make files executable (but directories must be executable in order to be accessed)

Comment: oh ok, thats how this works. Cool, now I understand this. Thank you!